# How to encode each of the 26 letters onehot to generate 26 corresponding RGB pictures?

Tags: python, image, one-hot-encoding

How to encode each of the 26 letters onehot to generate 26 corresponding RGB pictures?I need to change the input letters into the form of onehot code to generate the corresponding letter pictures. I don't know what to do. Please ask for help

Comment: Please read again your question, think for a few minutes. Do you think there is a chance we can understand what you want? I have no idea.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe it clearly. The problem is that 26 letters need to be transformed into one dot vector, and then the corresponding letter image is generated through one dot encoding vector

Comment: You **must** provide a meaningful input/output example and the code you tried to write yourself

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.